# OCMod not finding blocks of code

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart-module

What is up with OCMod?  It will not find a block of code [that I need to replace]

Here is what I have in my mod:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>

  <file path="catalog/controller/information/information.php">

  <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[$data['breadcrumbs'] = array();]]></search>
        <add position="after"><![CDATA[$template = 'newproducts.tpl';]]></add>
  </operation>

  <operation>
        <search>
          <![CDATA[
                if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/information.tpl')) {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/information.tpl', $data));
      } else {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/information/information.tpl', $data));
      }
          ]]>
        </search> 
        <add position="after"><![CDATA[echo 'booooooger';]]></add>
  </operation>

  </file>  

</modification>
```

the First operation works just fine, the second does not find the block of code in the search [and it is there exactly - I've synced and diffed the files it IS there]  Here is the error:

```
FILE: catalog/controller/information/information.php
CODE: $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
LINE: 8
CODE: if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/information.tpl')) {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/information.tpl', $data));
      } else {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/information/information.tpl', $data));
      }
NOT FOUND!
```

I've tried the search with the trim attribute set to both true and false... no luck.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use single line search, if you want to search multiline then you need to use regex or [more](http://helpforsite.com/en/blog/ocmod-multiline-fix/).

```
<operation>
        <search>
            <![CDATA[
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/information/information.tpl', $data));
            ]]>
        </search>
        <add position="after" offset="1">
         <![CDATA[
          echo 'booooooger';
         ]]>
       </add>
    </operation>
```